# Link in a link?

Tags: forms, hyperlink, portal

I have the following process:

1. 1st page with the following outbound link "http://tribecastudios.zingfit.com/reserve/index.cfm?action=Reserve.buySeries&seriesid=2"
2. This links to to a Sign in / Sign up button. User has to click on "Sign Up" (2nd page)
3. Then, the user gets redirected to a 3rd page: the sign up form.
4. Once the sign up form processed, the user gets redirected to the checkout screen depending on the URL clicked on on the 1st page.

I can only impact Page 1 and then the header and footer of page 2 as it is a 3rd party system.

What I want to achieve: when clicking on the first link on the 1st page, the user is directed to the sign up form but with the browser history of having gone through 2 links so that he gets the appropriate checkout.

So I need a link in a link...?

Thank you so much for reading this. Please comment if you have any questions, comments or idea on how I could make this work

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just encode a URI and add it as a querystring parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can urlencode another URL and append it as a querystring parameter at any point in your flow to maintain a history and a trail. You can add more than one. For example:

```
http://tribecastudios.zingfit.com/reserve/index.cfm
?action=Reserve.buySeries
&seriesid=2
&stepOne=http%3A%2F%2Ftribecastudios.zingfit.com%2Freserve%2Fpage1
&stepTwo=http%3A%2F%2Ftribecastudios.zingfit.com%2Freserve%2Fpage2
```